# Write text near a table

Tags: tables, itemize, tufte

I can write an `itemize` on the right of a table in a tufte-book class like in the figure :[image]

The code that I wrote is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, justified]{tufte-book}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref, lipsum, booktabs, lettrine}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{arvard}{RGB}{165, 28, 48}
\sectionfont{\color{arvard}}

\begin{document}            
   \chapter{Progettazione logica}
       \section{Tavola dei volumi}
           \begin{tabular}{lcr%
              S[table-format=3]%
              S[table-format=3]%
              S[table-format=1.1]
             }
            \toprule
            Concetto & Tipo & Volume\\
            \midrule
            Utente          &  E     & \SI{11e7}{}\\
            Immagini        & E     & \SI{2e10}{}\\ 
            Bacheca      &    E     & \SI{15e8}{}\\
            Argomenti      & E  & \SI{25e2}{}\\
            \midrule

            Follow               & A     & \SI{17,5e6}{} \\
            Inserisce            & A    & \SI{5e6}{} \\
            Pin                     & A     & \SI{511e7}{}\\
            Like & A& \SI{4e11}{}\\
            Include            & A & \SI{2e2}{}\\
            Possiede & A& \SI{2e2}{}\\
            Segue & A & \SI{1,5e5}{} \\
            Tipologia          & A & \SI{25e2}{}\\
            Somiglia           & A & \SI{11e2}{}\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}

    \section{Tavola delle operazioni}       
        Analizzando i requisiti, abbiamo dedotto che le operazioni svolte con maggiore frequenza sono:

        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{clcr%
                S[table-format=3]%
                S[table-format=3]%
                S[table-format=1.1]
                }
                \toprule
                Operazione & Descizione & Tipo & Frequenza\\
                \midrule
                1    & Registrazione di un nuovo utente        &  I     & \SI{3e4}{}\\
                2   & Caricamento di una immagine               & I     & \SI{3e6}{}\\
                3   & Creazione di una bacheca                      & I     & \SI{3e6}{}\\
                4   & Apprezzamento di una immagine         & I     & \SI{12e6}{}\\
                5   & Salvataggio di una immagine                & I     & \SI{17,5e6}{} \\
                6   & Seguire una bacheca                            & I    & \SI{5e6}{} \\
                7   & Eliminazione di un'utente                      & B    & \SI{2,5e3}{} \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \\\bigskip
            \begin{itemize}
                \item I valori delle colonna ``Frequenza'' sono espressi al giorno
            \end{itemize}
        \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `minipage` environment to archive this. You used the S column from `siunitx` wrong in your MWE so I fixed that up.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, justified]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref, lipsum, booktabs, lettrine}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{arvard}{RGB}{165, 28, 48}
\sectionfont{\color{arvard}}

\begin{document}            
   \chapter{Progettazione logica}
       \section{Tavola dei volumi}
         \begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
           \begin{tabular}{@{}lcS[table-format=3.1e2]@{}}
            \toprule
            Concetto & Tipo & {Volume} \\
            \midrule
            Utente          &  E     & 11e7\\
            Immagini        & E     & 2e10\\ 
            Bacheca      &    E     & 15e8\\
            Argomenti      & E  & 25e2\\
            \midrule

            Follow               & A     & 17,5e6 \\
            Inserisce            & A    & 5e6 \\
            Pin                     & A     & 511e7\\
            Like & A& 4e11\\
            Include            & A & 2e2\\
            Possiede & A& 2e2\\
            Segue & A & 1,5e5 \\
            Tipologia          & A & 25e2\\
            Somiglia           & A & 11e2\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
      \end{minipage}
       \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
            Accusamus laudantium sint placeat blanditiis libero. Excepturi voluptatibus tempore illo mollitia dolorem sequi eligendi consequatur. Minus et unde voluptas ea et. Quam voluptatem aliquid sunt nam qui illo. Distinctio neque aliquam pariatur fugiat aliquam ducimus. Ipsum est quia vero doloremque. Et voluptas repellat aut sequi incidunt. 
       \end{minipage}

    \section{Tavola delle operazioni}       
        Analizzando i requisiti, abbiamo dedotto che le operazioni svolte con maggiore frequenza sono:

        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}clcS[table-format=2.1e1]@{}}
                \toprule
                Operazione & Descizione & Tipo & {Frequenza}\\
                \midrule
                1    & Registrazione di un nuovo utente        &  I     & 3e4\\
                2   & Caricamento di una immagine               & I     & 3e6\\
                3   & Creazione di una bacheca                      & I     & 3e6\\
                4   & Apprezzamento di una immagine         & I     & 12e6\\
                5   & Salvataggio di una immagine                & I     & 17,5e6 \\
                6   & Seguire una bacheca                            & I    & 5e6 \\
                7   & Eliminazione di un'utente                      & B    & 2,5e3 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \\\bigskip
            \begin{itemize}
                \item I valori delle colonna ``Frequenza'' sono espressi al giorno
            \end{itemize}
        \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `S[table-format=3.1,table-figures-exponent = 2]` you can just write `S[table-format=3.1e2]`.